# an abnormal increase in loss when restoring the model in tensorflow2.12.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

my code:

```py
with strategy.scope():
        model = MoAt(
            in_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3),
            out_classes=total_labels,
            definition_name=definition_name,
            window_sides=window_sides,
            input_scaling="inception",
            stochdepth_rate=stochdepth_rate,
        )
        if args.checkpoint is None and args.origin==False:
            save_path = "outputs/%s_%s" % (definition_name, date_time)
        elif args.origin == False and args.checkpoint is not None:
            save_path = f'{checkpoint_dir}'
            model = tf.keras.models.load_model(args.checkpoint, compile=False) # 
        elif args.origin==True:
            save_path = "outputs/%s_%s" % (definition_name, date_time)
            origin_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("results/reference")
            i = 0
            for layer_original, layer_modified in zip(origin_model.layers[:-2], model.layers[:-2]):
                if layer_original.get_weights():
                    i+=1
                    layer_modified.set_weights(layer_original.get_weights())
            print("load from reference:", i)
        f1 = F1Score(total_labels, "micro", 0.4) # 
        rec_at_p65 = tf.keras.metrics.RecallAtPrecision(0.65, num_thresholds=1024) # 
        loss = AsymmetricLoss(
            reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE,
            gamma_neg=asl_gamma_neg,
            gamma_pos=asl_gamma_pos,
            clip=asl_clip,
        )
        curr_opt = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(
            learning_rate=warmup_learning_rate,
            decay=weight_decay_rate,
        )
        """ curr_opt.exclude_from_weight_decay(var_names = [
                r".*(gamma|beta|bias|mean|variance|embedding):0$"
            ]) """
        opt = GradientAccumulateOptimizer(optimizer=curr_opt, accum_steps=args.accu_steps) #
        model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss, metrics=[f1, rec_at_p65])

    t800 = tf.keras.callbacks.TerminateOnNaN()
    sched = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(scheduler, verbose=True)
        
    rmc_loss = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        "%s/variables/best_model/best"%save_path,
        save_best_only=True,
        save_freq="epoch",
        save_weights_only=True, 
    )
    
    
    tensorboard_step_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(f"{save_path}/tensorboard_step")
    tensorboard_epoch_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(f"{save_path}/tensorboard_epoch")

    cb_list = [t800, rmc_loss, sched, CustomCallback(), metrics_csv_logger]

    print("initial_epoch:", initial_epoch)
    print(model.summary())
    history = model.fit(
        training_dataset,
        validation_data=validation_dataset,
        initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
        epochs=total_epochs,
        steps_per_epoch= math.ceil(train_dataset_len // global_batch_size) , 
        validation_steps=math.ceil(val_dataset_len // global_batch_size ), 
        callbacks=cb_list,
    )
```

my command:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3 python train_moat_tfrecord.py  --checkpoint /Projects/SW-CV-outputs/MoAt2_03_08_2024_18h06m07s/variables/saved_model_2
```

the saved model:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP4Ei.png)

I can train the model but there are some DEBUG INFO:

```
[[{{node gradients/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/StatefulPartitionedCall_2}}]]
2024-03-14 10:18:40.901993: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'gradients/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/StatefulPartitionedCall' with dtype float and shape [?,112,112,128]
[[{{node gradients/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/StatefulPartitionedCall}}]]
2024-03-14 10:18:40.902095: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'gradients/StatefulPartitionedCall_grad/StatefulPartitionedCall_1' with dtype float and shape [?,1,1,1]
```

the biggest problem is the **loss:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Czsk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kABjt.png)

Why does such an abnormal loss curve appear?

my environment

```
tensorflow==2.12.0   
tensorflow_addons==0.20.0
```